# ExpressionEngine 3 photo file and signature file settings?

Tags: ee3, files

Same as EE2 where we can set avatar file settings, signature file settings and photo file settings Do we have something in EE3  where we can set file store location, height, width, max KB etc. for photo file and signature file ?

I search and found we can set avatar file settings but i didn't found same for Photo files and signature files. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found the default array saved in database that save those settings. I created my own setting form to update those settings.

If anyone wants to do so you can use this plugin:
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-members

Still, Let me know if you have any other solutions.